# Rotating a button in Unity UI by -180 on the Y and it stops working

Tags: unity, gui

If I rotate my button by -180 on the Y axis I can't even click on it. If for example I rotate it 180 on the Z axis everything is fine. Why does this happen and how can I fix it ?

Comment: It could be based on facing direction. A button rotated by 180 on z hasn't changed its facing relative to the camera (assuming typical UI setup) while one rotated 180 on the y axis is backwards. It could be that Unity only processes forward-facing objects when doing hit tests.

Comment: Thats what I thought but why on earth would they do this for the UI.

Comment: Mine is not to answer why. ;) Does setting x scale to -1 cause problems? If not that may be a workaround.

Comment: No scaling x works fine like always. I was just wondering about the Y rotation, but like a friend once said Unity is like voodoo magic.

Answer (score 3):

This also works, Canvas > Graphics Raycaster > Uncheck Ignore Reverse Graphics

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix is to set your Source Image to None, reset y rotation to 0, Color full transparent, Raycast Target Check. Then you add your Image as a child, set rotation y 180 and Uncheck Raycast Target (not needed anymore because the image is flipped, the raycast will pass trought it anyway). Set your child Image as Target Graphic in the Button component and there you go.